# Change the look of the media uploader

Tags: uploads, hooks

I have been trying to find out for a while now if there is a way to totally change the look of the pop up media uploader.

How can I alter the content and the layout of that page? Which hooks should I use, and will that be forwards compatible?

Answer (score 2):

As starting point there is this action that allows inserting CSS and Javascript into the upload window.

```
add_action( 'admin_head-media-upload-popup', 'wpse_70750_style_upload_iframe' );

function wpse_70750_style_upload_iframe() 
{
    ?>
    <style type="text/css">
        #media-upload, #media-upload .media-item .slidetoggle { background-color:#555 }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
        });     
    </script>  
    <?php
}
```

Other Q&A's that [use this hook](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=admin_head-media-upload-popup) may be interesting.

Then, you may dig into the core file `/wp-admin/includes/media.php` and investigate all `do_action` and `apply_filters` that are available.

Comment: great thanks. where should i place this code?

Comment: It could go in the theme's `functions.php`. But this kind of snippet is better placed in your own plugin, so it's theme independent. Just create a PHP file, add [a header information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin#Standard_Plugin_Information) in it, place in the plugins folder and activate.